# PDO wont connect to the database

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I've made a simple Database class to handle my database connections. But it's somehow not working? At first it wasn't working with MySQLi, so i tried PDO – which ain't working either.

I am however eager to make PDO work. I've already googled and searched here at StackOverflow, but without luck.

Here's my class:

```
class Database
{
    // Local 
    protected $_host    = "localhost";
    protected $_user    = "root";
    protected $_pass    = "root";
    protected $_database = "hs";
    protected $_connection;

    // Construct
    private function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hs', $this->_user, $this->_pass);
            $this->_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function login($usr, $pwd)
    {
        echo "hi";
    }
}
```

And here's the execution:

```
if(isset($_POST['hs_login']))
{
   $db = new Database;
   $db->login($_POST['hs_username'], $_POST['hs_password']);
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What is the error produced?

Comment: None at all, even with ERROR_REPORTING on.

I simply get a blank page.

Comment: Is the POST value set?

Comment: Your __construct method is `private`, make it `public`, it should work

Comment: Good eye, @bSaraogi.

Comment: Yes, it's true... Also, he has to instantiate the class with an opening and closing parentheses after it. e.g.: `$db = new Database();`

Comment: try to add this to the top of the script   error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch, guys! making `private` sure did help. I thought i already tried this, but apparently not.

Thanks again! :)

@bSaraogi, @Mike

Comment: @TiborB. That's not true... See http://codepad.viper-7.com/6QJLX4

Comment: *"None at all, even with ERROR_REPORTING on. I simply get a blank page."* - Are you "displaying" them? I.e.: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Mike: You're right. I apologize for that. It might just be my personal preference, as I prefer to use the parentheses anyways, even when I haven't given any parameters to my `__construct` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are always public so change that like so:

```
class Database
{
    // Local 
    protected $_host    = "localhost";
    protected $_user    = "root";
    protected $_pass    = "root";
    protected $_database = "hs";
    protected $_connection;

    // Construct
    public function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hs', $this->_user, $this->_pass);
            $this->_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function login($usr, $pwd)
    {
        echo "hi";
    }
}
```

Also, new Database is a method call so change that like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['hs_login']))
{
   $db = new Database;
   $db->login($_POST['hs_username'], $_POST['hs_password']);
}
```

Comment: Constructors are NOT ALWAYS public.

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to point out, that there are some cases, when you can use private constructors. One of the practical use of them is with Databases, so it's relevant in your case as well. This design pattern is called Singleton pattern, and it relies on static method calls. You don't have to instantiate the class, as instantiation is handled by the class itself. I've put together an example:

```
<?php
  class Database {
    private static $instance = null;
    private $db;
    private static $last_result;

    private function __construct() {
      try {
        $pdo_param = array(
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=YOUR_HOSTNAME;dbname=YOUR_DBNAME", "YOUR_USERNAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD", $pdo_param);
      }
      catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

    private static function getInstance() {
      if (self::$instance == null) {
        self::$instance = new self();
      }
      return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function query($sql) {
      try {
        $instance = self::getInstance();
        $stmt = $instance->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        self::$last_result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return self::$last_result;
      }
      catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

    public static function prepare($sql, $params) {
      try {
        $instance = self::getInstance();
        $stmt = $instance->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        self::$last_result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return self::$last_result;
      }
      catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
      }
    }
  }

  $users = Database::query("SELECT * FROM users");
  $filtered_users = Database::prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", array(":username" => "john_doe"));
?>
<pre><?php
  print_r($users);
  print_r($filtered_users);
?></pre>
```

Singleton design pattern is really useful when you want to make sure, that there's ONLY ONE instance of a class in any given time.

Comment: Brilliant... a downvote because someone can't understand static calls.